# Iterate over object's property

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects. Each object has a title and a link.

```
[Object { title="Do it", reslink="http://img-9gag-ftw.9cac.../photo/a5PrnLE_460s.jpg"},
Object { title="\n \n ...le \n ", reslink="http://img-9gag-ftw.9cac.../photo/aE17NWG_460s.jpg"}, 
Object { title="\n \n ...es \n ", reslink="http://img-9gag-ftw.9cac...oto/a2Y5RqD_460s_v1.jpg"}]
```

I need to:

1. create an  element on the page for each title and
2. create an  element for each reslink

What is the easiest way to accomplish that?

Comment: since it is an array a for loop will be the fastest you can use other things like `$.each` from JQuery or `Array.prototype.map` or `Array.prototype.forEach` any way it is all a matter of coding it

Comment: Could you please provide an example, I am getting lost with syntax when trying to utilize any of those.

Comment: The easiest way is the way you did it : asking other people to do it. Unfortunately, that's not the point of SO. You need to show us what you've tried that didn't worked.

Comment: `var $titles = arrOfObjects.map(function(o) { return $('<a>', { title: o.title, href: o.reslink }) });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
for(var i in objects){
  var h1 = '<h1>' + objects[i].title + '</h1>';
  var href = '<a href="' + objects[i].reslink + '">linkText</a>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect. I was using this construction a bit wrong. I was putting the property name instead of new variable in (var i in objects).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `map` method to create an element for each array item.

This for example would create an array of links that has the `title` property as text and the `reslink` property as `href`:

```
var links = $.map(objects, function(o){
  return $('<a>', { href: o.reslink }).text(o.title)[0];
});
```

The result is an array of elements, that you can for example append in the page:

```
$('#someElement').append(links);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily the easiest (shortest) way, but using the DOM API can be much cleaner (and potentially faster) than hacking around with `innerHTML` and the like.

My solution:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var header = document.createElement('h1');
    header.textContent = array[i].title;
    // append the DOM element to another element (maybe to body)
    document.body.appendChild(header);

    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', array[i].reslink);
    // append the DOM element
    document.body.appendChild(link);
}
```

Probably you don't want to append it to the end of the body, but you get the idea. If you want to append it to somewhere else, use `#getElementById()` or `#querySelector()` to find the parent element, and append it there instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop to iterate over them. Then user jQuery's functions([append](http://api.jquery.com/append/), [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/), and so on...) to insert new elements.

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to create, but here goes...
Example:

```
for(var i=0; i < list.length; i++)
{
   var titleElement = "<title>" + list[i].title + "</title>";
   var linkElement = "<a href=" + list[i].reslink +">" + list[i].title + "</a>";
   $('#whereToInsertSelector').append(titleElement);
   $('#whereToInsertSelector2').append(linkElement);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cz7kwayq/) of what I think you are trying to accomplish.

### JavaScript

```
NineGagPosts = [{
    title: "Can't be the only one",
    reslink: "http://img-9gag-ftw.9cache.com/photo/avgPd9n_700b_v1.jpg"
}, {
    title: "This a**hole",
    reslink: "http://img-9gag-ftw.9cache.com/photo/aqNLejQ_700b.jpg"
}, {
    title: "She looks fun",
    reslink: "http://img-9gag-ftw.9cache.com/photo/a2Y5K2E_700b_v1.jpg"
}];

window.addEventListener("load", readPosts);

function readPosts() {

    for (var i = 0, l = NineGagPosts.length; i < l; i++) {
        var post = NineGagPosts[i];
        var title = document.createElement("h1");
        var image = new Image();
        title.innerHTML = post.title;
        image.src = post.reslink;
        image.width = 250;
        document.body.appendChild(title);
        document.body.appendChild(image);
    }

}
```

When the page loads (to access `document.body`) we call the `readPosts()` function, which will iterate over all the posts and create a `<h1>` element for the title and a `<img>` element for the actual post image, and then append them to the `<body>`.

Hope this helps!